# External USB or GigE Camera on an iPhone

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision, webcam, gige-sdk

I'm working on a vision project that is capturing videos with a dedicated app on an iPhone. Since the footage was only used to replay and watch, the rolling shutter effect was no issue.

Now the idea is to use the footage for computer vision. So a global shutter camera is a requirement now. I'm asking for tips and hints on connecting industrial USB or GigE cameras to iPhones. The idea is to still use all the functionality of the app and 'just' add the option to use external USB or GigE ethernet cameras.

I was not able to find any information regarding AVFoundation and GigE

This is my reasearch so far:

[OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/dc8/tutorial_video_processing.html)(no mention for external cameras)

[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup) (refering to internal cameras as well)

[AVcapturedevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceinput) (this should pick up any connected devices, but there is no mention about suported devices or GigE)

Im happy for any suggestions and/or experiences.

Julian

Comment: What kind of resolution and framerate and pixel-type do you need? Maybe it is easier to send the images (e.g. from a raspberry pi) via wifi to your phone, if the bandwidth is sufficent?

Comment: Otherwise I would suggest to ask distributors like Keyence or Stemmer Imaging about your needs, or directly to specific producers like Allied Vision or FLIR.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It seams that a embedded system is the way to go.